# t-distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, sample

I would like to find the `t-value` for 90% confidence interval with 17 observation.

In Excel, I can do this calculation with `t=T.INV.2T(.10, 16)=1.75` however in R I cannot find the correct way to get the same result.

`qt(p = 1-.9, df = 17-1) = -1.34`

`qt(p = (1-.9)/2, df = 17-1) = -1.75 # trying with two-tailed?`

What is the function R doing the same computation as `T.INV.2T` in Excel.

Similarly, we have also `T.DIST.2T` in Excel, what is the same function in R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the `1 - .1 / 2 = 0.95` quantile from the t-distribution with `17 - 1 = 16` degrees of freedom:

```
qt(0.95, 16)
# [1] 1.745884
```

**Explanation**

Excel describes `T.INV.2T` as

> Returns the two-tailed inverse of the Student's t-distribution

which is the quantile in math talk (though I would never use the term *2 tailed quantile*). The `p%` quantile `q` is defined as the point which satisfies `P(X <= q) >= p%`.

In `R` we get that with the function `qt` (*q* for quantile, *t*  for t-distribution). Now we just have to sort out what is meant by a `two-tailed inverse`. It turns out we are looking for the point `q` which satisfies `P(X <= -|q| | X >= |q|) >= .1`. Since the t-distribution is symmetrical this simplifies to `P(X >= |q|) >= .1 / 2`.

You can easily verify that in `R` with the use of the probability function `pt`:

```
pt(qt(0.05, 16), 16, lower.tail = TRUE) + 
pt(qt(0.95, 16), 16, lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, one other complement to my question, if we now pretend that we know the t-value (in this case 1.75) and the number of observations (16) - how can we get the CI ? I did try `pt(t_value, 16)` however, I am getting 95%

Comment: I guess this is `1 - (pt(qt(0.05, 16), 16, lower.tail = TRUE) + 
pt(qt(0.95, 16), 16, lower.tail = FALSE))` but I was wondering if there is a shorter form to get this value ?

Comment: `pt(t_value, 16)` gives you the *lower* tail. `pt(t_value, 16, lower.tail = FALSE)` would give you `0.05`. It is `0.05` (and not `0.1`) because we asked for the 2 sided quantile (again not a term i would use).

Answer (score 4):

As you correctly guessed, you do it by estimating the two-sided interval (alpha/2 = 0.1/2 = 0.05)

```
> qt(p = 0.95, df = 16)
[1] 1.745884
```

So 5 % off the upper and lower interval. I don't know Excel, but I am guessing that's what that function is doing.

As for dist, that is I assume the two-sided CDF

```
pt(-1.745884, df=16, lower.tail=T) +
pt(1.745884, df=16, lower.tail=F)
```

which is equal to `0.09999994`.